# How to define a dataset is a multiclass or multilabel problems

Tags: multilabel-classification, multiclass-classification

I am really confused with the multiclass and multilabel terminology, I have a dataset as below:

```
fe_1, fe_2, lb_1, lb_2
12, 34, A, A
34, 56, C, C
...
```

The requirement is that within lb_1 or lb_2, A,C can not happen at the same times, and between lb_1 and lb_2, A,A or C,C must show up, that means my final label should be [A,A],[A,C],[C,A],[C,C]
I think this should be a multiclass-multilabel problem, my colleague is more confident that it should be a multiclass problem only, while from sklearn package, it's a multilabel-indicator.
My question is,

1. if it's a multilabel problem, can the model knows which A, C belongs to which class? Will it accidently make A,C in lb_1 or A,C in lb_2 happen at the same time?
2. And for multilabel problems, label columns are allowed to happen at the same time and label values only for value 0/1, here the 0/1 means "presence or not"? what if I have more than two values in each label column and cannot be happened at the same time? For example, I replace A,C from lb_2 to B,D, and I need to make sure A,C in lb_1 and B,D in lb_2 cannot happen at the same time which means when I get a row of data, it should have 4 possible outcomes {[A,B],[A,D],[C,B],[C,D]}, this time sklearn package detect this is a multiclass-multioutput problem, so if it's true, can multiclass-multioutput make sure lb_1 and lb_2 show up at the same time and within lb_1 or within lb_2, different labels cannot happen at the same time?
3. If the multiclass-multioutput is what I need for my question, Can anyone suggest me a way to deal with imbalance issue in this multiclass-multioutput dataset? SMote Tomek Link seems can only deal with 1d array and no idea how to use the ADASYN, MLSMOTE also doesn't work if I assign my original lb_2 label from [A,C] to [B,D]

Appreciate your help and patience!

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, I should just get binary labels [a,a],[a,c],[c,a],[c,c] only, but the problem is that for this 2-label-binary-class model, how to create a model so that the model generate result a or c are from two labels not from either of them? Cause I have both a and c classes in these two labels, for multiclass portion, a and c classes in any label cannot show up at the same time and i need two labels must appear at the same time?

Comment: You're welcome. I've posted an answer below where I try to address your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood, you have two outputs (L1, L2) per sample whose labels can be: (A, A), (A, C), (C, A), (C, C). `sklearn` [defines this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html) as multilabel classification (2 or more outputs, where each output is binary).

Each output takes on one class from A or C (binary classification). The multilabel aspect is that each sample has *two* binary labels assigned to it. L1 can only predict one class at a time, because `sklearn` will see that it's binary. Same for L2 - it can only predict one class for each sample. The outputs from the model could be AA, AC, CA, CC. If you fit the model on data where the first column is L1 and the second column is L2, then the model's outputs will follow that order - i.e. the first output will be for L1, and the second will be for L2.

L1 can't predict two classes at the same time. So if you `.predict()`, you might get `L1=A, L2=C` for example. You could equivalently get the underlying probabilities using `.predict_proba()`: `L1=[0.7, 0.3], L2=[0.01, 0.99]`.

In your case, if AA and CC are not valid combinations, and you want to strictly prohibit them, you may reframe the problem as simply *binary classification*, where the only two allowed outputs are: 0 representing "AC" and 1 representing "CA". You'd need to delete the invalid L1-L2 combinations, map the two valid combinations to 0 ("AC") and 1 ("CA"), and fit a binary classifier to this new binary target.

---

Alternatively, if you don't want to delete the (A, A) and (C, C) samples, and keep it as a multilabel setup, then some options for minimising AA and CC predictions are below.

My initial thought is that the model will adapt to your data...so if your data reflects those constraints, a good model will mostly behave the desired way.

One way to influence the model in `sklearn` is to use the `sample_weight=` parameter when fitting. You can set the weight of (a,a) and (c,c) samples to zero, causing the model to ignore them and therefore the model will only be influenced by (a,c) and (c,a) labels.

An potential alternative is to use a framework like PyTorch, where you can penalise the model heavily for (a,a) and (c,c) predictions, which will push the model way from making such predictions, though it won't guarantee their absence.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience and the good answer and sorry for not making request clear, for my model, if L1=a, then L1 cannot be c at the same time but L2 can be c or a, what I am not sure is for this 2-label-binary-class model, if L1=a, will L1=c happen at the same time? cause we have both a and c in two labels, how does the model knows which c and which a belongs to which label?
And thank you for the suggestion, it seems quite instructive.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it was useful. I have updated my answer. L1 can only predict one class at a time, because `sklearn` will see that it's binary. Same for L2 - it can only predict one class for each sample. They do their predictions independently, so the outputs from the model could be AA, AC, CA, CC. If you fit the model on data where the first column is L1 and the second column is L2, then the model's outputs will follow that order - i.e. the first output will be for L1, and the second will be for L2.

Comment: Thanks for the updates, now I am more confident about my model now, by the way, to deal with the imbalance for this multilabel model, do you have any recommended package except MLSMOTE?

Comment: No worries. I assume the imbalance is something like: within L1 (or L2), you have a lot more of L1=A than L1=C (or more L2=A than L2=C). Section 1.12 of the sklearn User Guide provides a list of classifiers that accept multilabel data. `RandomForestClassifier` has a `class_weight=` parameter that will take imbalance into account during fitting. I am not sure about the best options in sklearn for handling imbalanced data. Probably worth asking a new question on this matter.